# How to change my default web browser when I'm at work?

Tags: macos

On my Mac I use Safari for personal stuff and Chrome for work-related web browsing.  I currently have Safari set to my system's default browser, but I would love to be able to change that setting over when I connect to my office WiFi network, so that links in emails and Slack open in Chrome instead.  Is it possible to configure some triggers in Automator or some other application that would switch the default browser over to Chrome when I join my office WiFi network and switch it back when I disconnect from it?

Comment: Little unknown fact about Safari is in the Develop menu item (Safari -> Advanced -> Show develop in menu bar) is an 'Open Page With' option to open in a different installed browser.

Comment: Do you want this automatically or can it be you click and application and it will detect the network and change accordingly?